# Read CollectionFS file from server's filesystem when hosted on meteor.com

Tags: meteor, amazon-ec2, collectionfs

Im trying let the user Upload a txt file and then let him click a button "analyze" and then perform some analysis.

I have the app working locally, Im using FS.Collection and FileSystem however I had several problems deploying to meteor.com. Here is my collection:

```
FS.debug = true;

Uploads = new FS.Collection('uploads', {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem('uploads')]
});
```

and here is how I try to read the uploaded file:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var readedFile = fs.readFileSync(process.env.PWD+'/.meteor/local/cfs/files/uploads/+file.copies.uploads.key, 'utf-8');
```

The above works in local but not after I deploy to meteor.com, in the debug messages I see something like this: `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory`

So I do not know how to read the file when the app is deployed, how would you do it?, or do you think I should deploy the app to Amazon EC2? Im afraid to deploy to amazon and have the same problem...

Comment: I suspect that meteor.com doesn't give you access to the local file system. If you use the `.url()` method on the collectionFS file object you can fetch it via http instead of trying to read it directly from the server. This will also protect you later when you decide to use gridfs or S3 as your storage adapter instead of server local disk.

Comment: You mean make an http get request in meteor with the url of the file?, if you can provide some simple example I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short example of using http to download a file that was uploaded via collectionFS.

```
var file = Uploads.findOne({ _id: myId }); // or however you find it
  HTTP.get(file.url(),function(err,result){
    // this will be async obviously
    if ( err ) console.log("Error "+err+" downloading file"+myId);
    else {
      var content = result.content; // the contents of the file
      // now do something with it
    }
  });
```

Note that you must `meteor add http` to get access to the http package.

Comment: contentos de ser de ayuda

Comment: Ho you forgot to add that you first need to `meteor add http` package for use HTTP.get

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the package you want:

https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads

it has a nice UI too and much less trouble than FSCollection.